# how can i change the content in tab bar with bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a project with html,css,bootsrap4 that it has a search box with multiple tabs... the problem is that when I change the tab, the tab-content won't change and new content add to the old content.
what's the problem?

use can see the codes here:

```
[Text](https://codepen.io/setarezre/pen/qBRVjJe?editors=1000)
```

```css
.searchBox {
  background: #f6f7fb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(24, 104, 188, .07);
  direction: rtl;
}

.searBox-top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.searchBox .adult-search button {
  border-left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.searchBox .child-search button {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.searchBox .child-search {
  padding-right: 0;
}

li a {
  color: #35357a;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blueviolet;
}

li h2 {
  font-size: medium;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: myfont;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-family: myfont;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab-content {
  font-family: myfont;
  font-weight: bold;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}

html {
  direction: rtl;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="searBox-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="searchBox">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#flight">
                <h2>
                  پرواز
                </h2>
              </a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#train">

                <h2>قطار</h2>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#booking">
                <h2>ویلا و اقامتگاه</h2>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#hotel">
                <h2>
                  هتل
                </h2>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tour">
                <h2>تور</h2>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- start tab content flight-->

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="flight" class="tab-pane active">
              <div class="form-check-inline" style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top: 15px;">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">
                          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="option1" > یک طرفه
                        </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
                          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="option2"> رفت و برگشت
                        </label>
              </div>

              <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col" style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="مبدا">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col" style=" padding-left: 15px;">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="مقصد">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="چند نفر؟">
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="form-row" style="padding-bottom: 15px;  padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ رفت">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ برگشت">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-lg-12 justify-content-center" style="padding-bottom: 15px; ">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="جستجو" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
              </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- end tab content flight-->

          <!-- start tab content train-->

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="train" class="tab-pane fade">
              <div class="form-check-inline" style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top: 15px;">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="option1" > یک طرفه
                    </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="option2"> رفت و برگشت
                    </label>
              </div>

              <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col" style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="مبدا">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col" style=" padding-left: 15px;">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="مقصد">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="چند نفر؟">
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="form-row" style="padding-bottom: 15px;  padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ رفت">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ برگشت">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="جستجو" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
              </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- end tab content train-->

          <!-- start tab content vila-->

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="booking" class="tab-pane fade">
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="نام شهر">
                </div>
              </form>
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ ورود ">
                </div>
              </form>
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="مدت اقامت ">
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="col" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="جستجو" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--end tab content vila-->

          <!-- start tab content hotel-->

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="hotel" class="tab-pane fade">
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="نام شهر">
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="form-row" style="padding-bottom: 15px;  padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ ورود">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ خروج">
                </div>
              </div>
              <form>
                <div class="form" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="مدت اقامت ">
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="col" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="جستجو" style="padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--end tab content hotel-->


          <!--start tab content tour-->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tour" class="tab-pane fade">
              <form>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 ">
                    <p style="padding-right: 15px;">چند نفرید؟</p>
                    <div class="form-row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                      <div class="col">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="" style="padding-left: 5px;">&nbsp;خانم
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">&nbsp;آقا
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="" >&nbsp;کودک
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="" >&nbsp;سالمند
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <hr>

              <div class="row" style=" padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
                <div class="col col-sm-12">
                  <p style="padding-right: 15px;"> سفرتون چند روز باشه؟</p>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control ">
                </div>
                <div class="col col-sm-12">
                  <p style="padding-right: 15px;"> کی حرکت کنیم؟</p>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control ">
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>

              <div class="row" style=" padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <div class="col">
                  <p style="padding-right: 15px;"> تور از کجا شروع بشه؟</p>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control ">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


          <!--end tab content tour-->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab container "tab-content" should be just one.
You are repeating the container so the content is not toggling, just appearing.
The common structure for tabs is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- one "tab-content" container for all tabs -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>Tab1</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/GRrOvZE

Comment: thank you :) you solved my problem :) I'm rookie